# Rails create without redirect or refresh

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I've got a javascript script on a view that submits data to a rails controller via a post method :

```
$.post("/user_answers?user_answer[question_id]=" + gon.questions[questionNum]["id"] + "&correct=true")
```

and basically the controller takes this post and updates or creates a new user_answer.

```
def create
  @user_answer = current_user.user_answers.find_or_initialize_by(answer_params)    
  # Handles box assignment based on correct or wrong answer
  if params[:correct] == "true"
    @user_answer.box = 1
  elsif params[:correct] == "false"
    @user_answer.box = 2
  end
  @user_answer.save
end
```

This works perfectly, except I noticed that the controller tries to redirect to user_answers/create and returns an error because that doesn't exist. This doesn't affect the user's experience at all, but it does make an extra request to the server for no reason.

The thing is, I don't want to redirect to anything or refresh to anything, because the post just needs to update the record. The view updates itself using Javascript. How do I remove the default redirect_to action in .save or .create?

Comment: In that case if you are submitting one form then you have to set remote to true if this is a form to which you are passing a value. I suggest have a look at this http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Comment: I have, but it basically gives a similar problem - it creates a get request has to be processed by the server.

Comment: It's a patch but have you tried redirect_to back?

Comment: Ah, yes, I have. It also sends a get request and re-selects all the variables from the model, which is annoying because I do something like 10 posts on that particular view (it's like a... quiz.). Out of 4 buttons you click one and it sends a POST to the controller while updating to the next question. The questions are pre-selected and in a JS variable on the view. I'm trying to figure out from your link if I can set remote in the jquery $.post method or if I have to switch to $.ajax...

Comment: $.ajax will definitely do. $.ajax for the win :)

Answer (score 1):

You can throw in

```
return false
```

wherever you want the code execution in your action to stop